# How to skip a function call from another function if a condition is met

Tags: python

I'm writing a game and I need to skip the `MOBTURN()` if and only if the player succeeds at the flee roll.

My code pertaining:

```py
   def PLAYERFLEE():
        fleechance=random.randint(1,10)
        global mhp
        global mgold
        global php
        if fleechance>=escapechance:
            mhp=int(0)
            mgold=int(0)
            print('You fled')
            
        else:
            fleedmg=(random.randint(1,10)+mrdmg)
            php=php-fleedmg
            print(f'You took {fleedmg} damage!')


    def MOBTURN():
        mobatk=random.randint(1,10)+mdmg-parmor
        global php
        php=php-mobatk
        print(f'Mob HP:{mhp} Mob Damage:{mdmg} Mob Range Damage:{mrdmg} Mob Armor:{marmor} Mob Stun Status:{mstun}')
        print(f'You took {mobatk} damage!')


    def PLAYERTURN():
        action=input(f'Your stats are HP: {php}, DMG: {pdmg}, Range DMG: {prdmg}, Stun Status: {pstun}. What will you do? (atk/ratk/flee/stun)')
        if action==str('atk'):
            PLAYERATTACK()
        elif action==str('ratk'):
            PLAYERRANGEATTACK()
        elif action==str('flee'):
            PLAYERFLEE()
        elif action==str('stun'):
            PLAYERSTUN()
        else:
            print('Please choose an option from the parentheses!')
            PLAYERTURN()
        

    def FIGHT():
        mobalive=True
        while mobalive==True:
            PLAYERTURN()
            if mhp<=0:
                mobalive=False
            MOBTURN()
```

Comment: It's hard to debug your code because parts are missing and it's not formatted properly, but if you want `MOBTURN()` to only execute once a specific criterion is met, then put an `if criterion:` in front of it

Comment: Also don't call PLAYERTURN() from PLAYERTURN() to go back to the top.  Use a `while` loop and exit it when you get a valid action.

Comment: Don't use `global`. If you expect your function to work on something predefined, just pass that as arguments to it. Also, `int(0)` doesn't make any sense. Just use a plain old `0` instead.

Comment: ... and there are too many problems with the code that we can't even start to try to answer your main question.

Comment: Thank y'all. I'm a teenager still learning Python and coding. I didn't even think about that.

Answer (score -1):

Your code is quite unclear since it is missing a lot, however, I believe what you need to do is, wherever you check if the player succeeds at flee roll, return True. Only execute MOBTURN() if flee roll doesn't return True.

Comment: That's not an answer. It is more suited as a comment. Please, spend some time reading ["How do I write a good answer?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

> ... if and only if the player succeeds at the flee roll.

Return a value from the function then use a conditional statement to call `MOBTURN`

```
....

    def PLAYERFLEE():
        ....
        if fleechance>=escapechance:
            ...
            print('You fled')
            return True
            
        else:
            fleedmg=(random.randint(1,10)+mrdmg)
            php=php-fleedmg
            print(f'You took {fleedmg} damage!')
            return False
    ....
```

---

```
    def PLAYERTURN():
        ...
        elif action==str('flee'):
            return PLAYERFLEE()
        ...
```

---

```
    def FIGHT():
        ...
        while mobalive==True:
            success = PLAYERTURN()
            ...
            if success: MOBTURN()
            ...
```

---

In my example of `PLAYERTURN` the other cases will return `None` unless you specify something.

Comment: As an experienced user, your answer should not contain nonsense practices like `int(0)`, or `str('flee')`, or even `while mobalive==True:`. Let alone the lack of adherence to [PEP8, Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommendations.

Comment: Fair enough but I was not about to correct or re-write **all** of the OP's example.